# How To Add Specific Keys In Nested Dictionary In Python

Tags: python, function, dictionary, for-loop, nested

I may be formatting this dictionary wrong (my first time doing this)

I have a dictionary of every province with corrected ID and added it to value "Canada". I'm trying to add the population of ALL the provinces in the nested dictionary

```
    ontario = dict(capital="Toronto", largest="Toronto", population=14826276)
    quebec = dict(capital="Quebec City", largest="Montreal", population=8604495)
    nova_Scotia = dict(capital="Halifax", largest='Halifax', population=992055)
    new_Brunswick = dict(capital="Fredricton", largest='Moncton', population=789225)
    manitoba = dict(capital="Winnipeg", largest="Winnipeg", population=1383765)


canada = {ontario, quebec, nova_Scotia, new_brunswick, manitoba, british_columbia, prince_edward_island, saskatchewan, alberta, newfoundland_and_labrador}


 for key, value in canada.items():
        if value and 'population' in value.keys():
            # Adding all values of population to receive total population of canada
            sum += value['population']
            print(sum)
```

thanks again in advance.

Comment: Are you getting errors? If so, what errors? Or, what is not working as you expect?

Comment: I think this is the easiest way for this... `sum_ = sum(map(lambda p: p["population"], canada))`. FYI, the way you loop it is wrong since `canada` here is a `set` not a `dictionary`.

Comment: @enaielei ah, i see. i think thats the problem i'm having, i'm getting a TypeError: unhasable type.  How would i convert this list to a dictionary?

Comment: @jump Why would you want it as a `dict`? So that you can access it as `canada["ontario"]["population"]` for example? If that's the case then do like how you did it in your provinces... `canada = dict(ontario=ontario)`. Also, if you have missed it, the easiest way to get the sum is through the code I provided using the `sum` function.

Comment: your `canada` is not `dictionary` but `set()`. You would need rather `canada = {'regions': [ontario, quebec, ...]}` or `canada = {"Ontario": ontarion, "Quebec": quebec}` and then you could do (after `for`-loop) `canada["total_population"] = sum`

Answer (score 1):

You didn't create `dictionary` but `set` (which doesn't have `keys`)

To create dictionary you would need `keys` like

```
canada = {1:ontario, 2:quebec, 3:nova_scotia, 4:new_brunswick, 5:manitoba}

canada = {"Ontario":ontario, "Quebec":quebec, "Nova Scotia":nova_scotia, "New Brunswick":new_brunswick, "Manitoba":manitoba}
```

and then you can use `canada.items()` and sum population

(I use variable `total` because there is function `sum()`)

```
# --- before `for`-loop ---

total = 0

# --- `for`-loop ---

for key, value in canada.items():
    total += value['population']

# --- after `for`-loop ---

print(total)
```

or shorter

```
total = sum(value['population'] for value in canada.values())
```

and then you can add to this dictionary

```
canada['total'] = total
```

---

Full code:

```
ontario = dict(capital="Toronto", largest="Toronto", population=14826276)
quebec = dict(capital="Quebec City", largest="Montreal", population=8604495)
nova_scotia = dict(capital="Halifax", largest='Halifax', population=992055)
new_brunswick = dict(capital="Fredricton", largest='Moncton', population=789225)
manitoba = dict(capital="Winnipeg", largest="Winnipeg", population=1383765)

canada = {1:ontario, 2:quebec, 3:nova_scotia, 4:new_brunswick, 5:manitoba}#, british_columbia, prince_edward_island, saskatchewan, alberta, newfoundland_and_labrador

total = 0
for key, value in canada.items():
    total += value['population']
print(total)

#total = sum(value['population'] for value in canada.values())

canada['total'] = total

print(canada)
```

Answer (score 0):

1. I only added the listed 5 provinces into the nested dictionary.
2. I used a for loop to calculate the total population of Canada (the
   sum of the 5 listed provinces).

Note that my nested dictionary has the same format as a normal dictionary,
"a key : value" --> "1 : ontario"

```
ontario = dict(capital="Toronto", largest="Toronto", population=14826276)
quebec = dict(capital="Quebec City", largest="Montreal", population=8604495)
nova_Scotia = dict(capital="Halifax", largest='Halifax', population=992055)
new_Brunswick = dict(capital="Fredricton", largest='Moncton', population=789225)
manitoba = dict(capital="Winnipeg", largest="Winnipeg", population=1383765)

canada = {1:ontario, 2:quebec, 3:nova_Scotia, 4:new_Brunswick, 5:manitoba}
#canada = {ontario, quebec, nova_Scotia, new_brunswick, manitoba, british_columbia, prince_edward_island, saskatchewan, alberta, newfoundland_and_labrador}

sum = 0
for providence in canada:
    # Adding all values of population to receive total population of canada
    sum += (canada[providence]["population"])

print(sum)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this one.

```
ontario = dict(capital="Toronto", largest="Toronto", population=14826276)
quebec = dict(capital="Quebec City", largest="Montreal", population=8604495)
nova_Scotia = dict(capital="Halifax", largest='Halifax', population=992055)
new_Brunswick = dict(capital="Fredricton", largest='Moncton', population=789225)
manitoba = dict(capital="Winnipeg", largest="Winnipeg", population=1383765)

canada_list = [ontario, quebec, nova_Scotia, new_Brunswick, manitoba]
total = 0
for item in canada_list:
    # Adding all values of population to receive total population of canada
    total += item.get('population', 0)

print("Total: {}".format(total))
```

Output:

```
Total: 26595816
```